# Как обращаться к экспорту по умолчанию двух значений

Tags: javascript

В модуле index.js у нас такое:

```
import en from './en.js';
import ru from './ru.js';

export default { en, ru };
```

В модуле app.js у нас такое:

```
import resources from './index.js';
```

Я прежде никогда не сталкивался с экспортом по умолчанию сразу двух значений. Думал, что так делать нельзя. Как в модуле app.js правильно обратиться к тому, что мы получили из ru.js и en.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, разобрался. Мы просто передаём объект, в котором находятся ru и eng. Обращаться к ним можно так resources.ru и resources.eng

Comment: Конечно :) Ведь в экспорт передаётся один объект `{ ... }`, а вот уже в этом объекте может находиться всё что угодно и в разных кол-вах.